Query Returning Null Values in 'valid' Column for Date Range
I have a dataset with two columns, MinStation and MaxStation. In my query, I am attempting to create a column named valid to assign the value 0 for all entries within the specified date range. However, the query consistently returns null in the valid column. Can anyone help me pointing the mistake in my query?
My query:
select
    TransactionId
    ,ProductId
    ,StepId 
    ,TransactionDate
    ,ProductStation
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,MinStation
    ,MaxStation
    ,case
        when TransactionDate between MinStation and MaxStation then 0
    end as valid
from 
    #temp
order by
    ProductId
    ,TransactionDate asc
    ,ProductStation asc

Below the commands to create the #temp table and populate:
create table #temp(
    TransactionId int
    ,ProductId varchar(9)   
    ,StepId int
    ,TransactionDate datetime
    ,ProductStation varchar(5)
    ,StartDate datetime
    ,EndDate datetime
    ,MinStation datetime
    ,MaxStation datetime
)

go
insert into #temp values
(13570,'1001LX100',43,'2024-07-11 17:06:00.000','01: A','2024-07-11 17:06:00.000','7/11/24 17:06',NULL,NULL)
,(15189,'1001LX100',41,'2024-07-15 09:46:00.000','02: B','2024-07-15 09:46:00.000','7/15/24 9:46',NULL,NULL)
,(15427,'1001LX100',57,'2024-07-15 10:21:00.000','05: E','2024-07-15 10:21:00.000','7/15/24 10:21','7/15/24 10:21',NULL)
,(32539,'1001LX100',14,'2024-07-31 09:40:00.000','03: C','2024-07-31 09:40:00.000','7/31/24 9:40',NULL,NULL)
,(32652,'1001LX100',15,'2024-07-31 10:56:00.000','04: D','2024-07-31 10:56:00.000','7/31/24 10:56',NULL,NULL)
,(33360,'1001LX100',58,'2024-07-31 12:40:00.000','04: D','2024-07-31 12:40:00.000','7/31/24 12:40',NULL,'7/31/24 12:40')
,(33485,'1001LX100',60,'2024-07-31 14:20:00.000','08: H','2024-07-31 14:20:00.000','7/31/24 14:20',NULL,NULL)
,(33486,'1001LX100',56,'2024-07-31 14:20:00.000','08: H','2024-07-31 14:20:00.000','7/31/24 14:20',NULL,NULL)
,(36339,'1001LX100',46,'2024-08-02 16:14:00.000','09: I','2024-08-02 16:14:00.000','8/2/24 16:14',NULL,NULL)
,(14458,'2001LX240',43,'2024-07-12 13:02:00.000','01: A','2024-07-12 13:02:00.000','7/12/24 13:02',NULL,NULL)
,(17324,'2001LX240',41,'2024-07-17 08:26:00.000','02: B','2024-07-17 08:26:00.000','7/17/24 8:26',NULL,NULL)
,(17453,'2001LX240',14,'2024-07-17 09:20:00.000','03: C','2024-07-17 09:20:00.000',NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(17483,'2001LX240',15,'2024-07-17 09:45:00.000','04: D','2024-07-17 09:45:00.000',NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(20757,'2001LX240',57,'2024-07-19 10:20:00.000','05: E','2024-07-19 10:20:00.000','7/19/24 10:20','7/19/24 10:20',NULL)
,(26614,'2001LX240',58,'2024-07-25 11:32:00.000','04: D','2024-07-25 11:32:00.000',NULL,NULL,'7/25/24 11:32')
,(31988,'2001LX240',60,'2024-07-30 16:03:00.000','08: H','2024-07-30 16:03:00.000','7/30/24 16:03',NULL,NULL)
,(31990,'2001LX240',56,'2024-07-30 16:04:00.000','08: H','2024-07-30 16:04:00.000','7/30/24 16:04',NULL,NULL)
,(32483,'2001LX240',46,'2024-07-31 09:15:00.000','09: I','2024-07-31 09:15:00.000','7/31/24 9:15',NULL,NULL)
,(77245,'3001LX333',43,'2024-09-17 16:06:00.000','01: A','2024-09-17 16:06:00.000','9/17/24 16:06',NULL,NULL)
,(77270,'3001LX333',41,'2024-09-17 16:30:00.000','02: B','2024-09-17 16:30:00.000','9/17/24 16:30',NULL,NULL)
,(77295,'3001LX333',14,'2024-09-17 16:48:00.000','03: C','2024-09-17 16:48:00.000',NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(77309,'3001LX333',15,'2024-09-17 17:04:00.000','04: D','2024-09-17 17:04:00.000',NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(80851,'3001LX333',57,'2024-09-20 15:21:00.000','05: E','2024-09-20 15:21:00.000','9/20/24 15:21','9/20/24 15:21',NULL)
,(89269,'3001LX333',58,'2024-10-01 11:08:00.000','04: D','2024-10-01 11:08:00.000','10/1/24 11:08',NULL,'10/1/24 11:08')
,(89857,'3001LX333',60,'2024-10-01 15:22:00.000','08: H','2024-10-01 15:22:00.000','10/1/24 15:22',NULL,NULL)
,(89858,'3001LX333',56,'2024-10-01 15:22:00.000','08: H','2024-10-01 15:22:00.000','10/1/24 15:22',NULL,NULL)
,(90096,'3001LX333',46,'2024-10-02 08:23:00.000','09: I','2024-10-02 08:23:00.000','10/2/24 8:23',NULL,NULL)

This is the expected result in print screen:

you seem to have a bunch of NULL values for the station times.  you should probably wrap them with an NVL to allow them to be used in the BETWEEN clause.

Please don't use images for data, use table markdown.

I filled the MinStation and MaxStation with '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', but now the query return 0 where MaxStation have a different from '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'.

In the data you provided, there is no row with both min station and max station filled, hence the CASE expression defaults to NULL for all rows.

If you change the condition to WHEN TransactionDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate for example, some rows satisfy that, so they will get 0 as expected, see this sample fiddle. If this is not what you wanted to know, then improve your question and explain what is unclear to you.

You code reads CASE WHEN condition THEN 0 END with no ELSE part. Did you intend  CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END or CASE WHEN condition THEN 0 ELSE 1 END?  You may still need to modify your condition to handle null MnStation and MaxStation values.

You need to ensure that the MinStation and MaxStation columns contain values that meet your conditions. The data you provided primarily has null values in both columns, and no rows have values in both fields. As a result, it won't display 0; instead, it will display default null value.

I was able to solve it by creating it with the help of CTE (Common Table Expression), where I created a table with the ranges between stations without nulls and made a join with the main table. This returned the expected result.
Thank you guys for the advise about the null values!

Could you please improve both your question and your answer, so people can understand what exactly you really wanted to know and how you solved it?
